# Joomla 4 not showing error in admin Panel

Tags: joomla-4.x, error-reporting

I am using Joomla 4 and working on a custom module and getting this error in my Joomla admin site. My problem is I am unable to get the error details instead I only get this `Error: The 'atum' service key is already registered.: Using $this when not in object context`.
i am not getting which file which line number etc.

Under Global configuration I have set debug system to `yes` and Error reporting to `maximum`. I tried with different error reporting options but the result was same.
Even in my php.ini file error display is On. Am I missing something?

Admin template is the default one. Joomla 4 Alpha version the current version.

Comment: Have you looked at this issue, https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/30119 ?  Beta 4 was just announced so being at any Alpha level is not going to be current.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have to wait for a stable version.

Comment: Why do you have to wait for a stable release? If you found your problem on an Alpha release and the current Beta release appears to resolve your problem then why not use it.